# How can I fit ImageViews in TableRow?

Tags: android, imageview, tablelayout, tablerow

How can I show ImageViews in TableRow at same size?

I want to create 4 ImageViews in TableRow. 
The Images I want to use are all same size but these are too big to fit in display at a time.

Then, I used TableLayout.setColumnShrinkable() but it shrank only first two Images.

How can I fit all ImageViews to same size?

Comment: show code with xml

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know I had to show source code.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood setColumnShrinkable() method.
I have two rows and four images in each row, so I called the method twice.

However, I had to call the method four times.
That was the reason why the method shrank only first two images.

I apologize for all my fault.
I achieved what I want thanks to MPG's xml.

Thank you for your help.

XML

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView6" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView7" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView8" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Activity java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            table.setColumnShrinkable(i, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try this way if any query let me know....
   I have updated my code...

**You can use one way**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/box" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/box" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/box" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/box" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

**You can use Second way**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/box" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/box" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/box" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/box" />

 </TableRow>
```

Comment: Please read the `Question Carefully` first before you answer it. He want this mechanism with using `Table Layout` not with `Linear Layout`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.